# SQL with parameter and wildcard

Tags: mysql, ado, delphi-2010

simply want to run an SQL statement that takes a letter(s) entered into a textbox and returns results where names of books have the same first letter(s). E.g. if H is entered, then books such as 'Happy Days','Heaven', 'Hoping for Tomorrow' would be returned. Here is what I have used, but i get no results in my DBgrid.  The textbox into which the letter is entered is edtBookTitle.text.

```
qbook.SQL.Text:='SELECT BookID,BookTitle FROM Book WHERE BookTitle LIKE edtBookTitle.text%';
```

Comment: Applied your recommendation (see edit above). Got message 'Unknown column 'edtBookTitle.text' in 'where clause'. Not sure why this is appearing. I had to use speech marks " "instead of ' '.

Answer (score 3):

Your `LIKE` is incorrect. It should be

```
SELECT .... WHERE BookTitle LIKE CONCAT(edtBookTitle.text, '%')
```

You hav a bare `%` there, which in MySQL will be the arithmetic modulo operator, missing an operand. So your query is a flat-out  syntax error.

Comment: Tried this, but it is treating edtBookTitle.text as a column.

Comment: yes, because that's how you had it in your original query. if that's supposed to be a variable or something from your delphi code, thenyou'd need to build it into the query string to start with `query = "SELECT ... LIKE CONCAT(" + edtBookTitle.text + ", '%')` etc... remember: sql is just text until it reaches the DB server. You're writing a query, but it's still just text as far as your programming language is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo WHERE someColumn LIKE 'h%';
```

you might need to concatenate the wild card at the end of your query, it should be in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

It was a matter of tinkering with the apostrophes.

```
qbook.SQL.Text:='SELECT BookID,BookTitle FROM Book WHERE BookTitle LIKE CONCAT("'+edtBookTitle.text+'%")';
 qbook.open;
```

Comment: That produces `CONCAT("text%")`, which is not concatenating two strings. Use `CONCAT("'+edtBookTitle.Text+'", '%')` instead. And be careful, if `edtBookTitle.Text` already contains quoted in it, it will break the SQL.  Either use `QuotedStr()` or a parameterized query to account for that.